# How to define piecewise function in Python using numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sympy, piecewise

Following is the function I want to implement in python. I am getting Type Errors when defining a function. I tried defining using `numpy.piecewise` function object and also using just `elif` commands as a definition. I want to be able to then evaluate this function at different points as well as expressions like `f(X-1)` etc

This is my code:

```
from numpy import piecewise 
from scipy import *
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function
from sympy import Function
from sympy import *
h = 0.5 
a = -1
n = 2
x = Symbol('x')
expr = piecewise((0, x-a <=  -2*h), ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<=-h), (2*h**3/3-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), -h<= x-a<= 0), (2*(h**3/3)-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), 0<=x-a<=2*h), ((1/6)*(2*h-(x-a))**3, h<=x-a<=2*h), (0, x-a<=2*h))
p = lambdify((x, a,b,h), expr)

def basis(x,a,b, h):
    if x <= a-2*h:
        return 0;
    elif (x<=a-h) or (x >=2*h):
        return (1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3
    elif  (x-a<= 0) or (x-a >= -h):
        return (2*h**3/3-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)));
    elif (x<=2*h+a) or (x >= 0):
        return  (2*(h**3/3)-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)));
    elif (x<=a+2*h) or (x >= h):
        return (1/6)*(2*h-(x-a))**3; 
    elif x-a<=2*h:
        return 0

basis(x, -1,0.5,0)
```

Both ways I get this :

```
raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Comment: This seems more like a `sympy` question than `numpy`.  In any case your function call for `np.piecewise` is [not at all what the function expects](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) so that's probably part of the problem

Comment: Also, [don't just copy your question and change the title two hours later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64891325/defining-piecewise-function-in-python-getting-typeerror-cannot-determine-truth) - that's a good way to catch a question ban.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sympy's lambdify function to generate the numpy piecewise function. This is a simpler example but shows the general idea:

```
In [15]: from sympy import symbols, Piecewise                                                                                               

In [16]: x, a = symbols('x, a')                                                                                                   

In [17]: expr = Piecewise((x, x>a), (0, True))                                                                                    

In [18]: expr                                                                                                                     
Out[18]: 
⎧x  for a < x
⎨            
⎩0  otherwise

In [19]: from sympy import lambdify                                                                                               

In [20]: fun = lambdify((x, a), expr)                                                                                             

In [21]: fun([1, 3], [4, 2])                                                                                                      
Out[21]: array([0., 3.])

In [22]: import inspect                                                                                                           

In [23]: print(inspect.getsource(fun))                                                                                            
def _lambdifygenerated(x, a):
    return (select([less(a, x),True], [x,0], default=nan))
```

Comment: What formatting wizardry lets you put a curly brace in a codeblock like that?

Comment: Thank you so much for this however when I add more symbols for my function I am still getting the relational error?

Comment: @peaapod, while this answer works, it doesn't help you identify the underlying problem with your code.

Comment: @DanielF that's sympy's pretty printer as shown from the isympy console. The curly brace is actually three separate unicode characters.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Ahh, a different console.  Didn't get anything like that in `spyder` so I was confused.

Comment: You can also use sympy's `pretty` function. I find that isympy is the most convenient way to "show" the equations and also have something copy-pastable for SO, Github etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the length of this answer, but I think you need to see the full debugging process.  I had to look at the tracebacks and test small pieces of your code to identify the exact problem.  I've seen a lot of the `numpy` ambiguity error, but not this `sympy` relational error.

===

Lets look at the whole traceback, not just one line of it.  At the very least we need to identify which line of your code is producing the problem.

```
In [4]: expr = np.piecewise((0, x-a <=  -2*h), ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<
   ...: =-h), (2*h**3/3-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), -h<= x-a<= 0), (2*(h**3/3)-0.5
   ...: *(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), 0<=x-a<=2*h), ((1/6)*(2*h-(x-a))**3, h<=x-a<=2*h)
   ...: , (0, x-a<=2*h))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-893bb4b36321> in <module>
----> 1 expr = np.piecewise((0, x-a <=  -2*h), ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<=-h), (2*h**3/3-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), -h<= x-a<= 0), (2*(h**3/3)-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), 0<=x-a<=2*h), ((1/6)*(2*h-(x-a))**3, h<=x-a<=2*h), (0, x-a<=2*h))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

While `np.piecewise` is a numpy function, because `x` is a `sympy.Symbol`, the equations are sympy expressions.  `numpy` and `sympy` are not well integrated.  Somethings work, many others don't.

Did you try a small expression?  Good programming practice is to start with small pieces, making sure those work first.

Let's try something smaller:

```
In [8]: expr = np.piecewise((0, x-a <=  -2*h),
   ...:  ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<=-h))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-37ff62e49efb> in <module>
      1 expr = np.piecewise((0, x-a <=  -2*h),
----> 2  ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<=-h))

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

and smaller pieces:

```
In [10]: (0, x-a <=  -2*h)
Out[10]: (0, x + 1 ≤ -1.0)

In [11]: ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<=-h)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7bd9f95d077d> in <module>
----> 1 ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, -2*h<=x-a<=-h)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

In [12]: (1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3
Out[12]: 
                            3
1.33333333333333⋅(0.5⋅x + 1)
```

But:

```
In [13]: -2*h<=x-a<=-h
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-5ffb419cd443> in <module>
----> 1 -2*h<=x-a<=-h

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Simplify further:

```
In [14]: 0 < x < 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-59ba4ce00627> in <module>
----> 1 0 < x < 3

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

While `a < b < c` is allowed for regular Python variables and scalars, it does not work for `numpy` arrays, and evidently doesn't work for `sympy` variables either.

So the immediate problem has nothing to do with `numpy`.  You are using invalid `sympy` expressions!

===

Your `basis` function reveals an aspect of the same problem.  Again we need to look at the FULL traceback, and then test portions to identify the exact problem expression.

```
In [16]: basis(x, -1,0.5,0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b328f95b3c79> in <module>
----> 1 basis(x, -1,0.5,0)

<ipython-input-15-c6436540e3f3> in basis(x, a, b, h)
      1 def basis(x,a,b, h):
----> 2     if x <= a-2*h:
      3         return 0;
      4     elif (x<=a-h) or (x >=2*h):
      5         return (1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

This expression is a `sympy` relational:

```
In [17]: x <= -1
Out[17]: x ≤ -1
```

But we can't use such a relational in a Python `if` statement.

```
In [18]: if x <= -1: pass
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b56148a48367> in <module>
----> 1 if x <= -1: pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __nonzero__(self)
    382 
    383     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 384         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    385 
    386     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Python `if` is simple True/False switch; its argument must evaluate to one or the other.   The error is telling us that a `sympy.Relational` does not work.  `0 < x < 1` is variation on that basic Python `if` (it tests `0<x` and `x<1` and performs a `and`).

A variation on this that we often see in `numpy` (and `pandas`) is:

```
In [20]: 0 < np.array([0,1,2])
Out[20]: array([False,  True,  True])

In [21]: 0 < np.array([0,1,2])<1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bc1039cec1fc> in <module>
----> 1 0 < np.array([0,1,2])<1

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The `numpy` expression has multiple True/False values, and can't be used im a Python expression that requires a simple True/False.

## edit

Correctly expanding the two sided tests:

```
In [23]: expr = np.piecewise((0, x-a <=  -2*h),
    ...:  ((1/6)*(2*h+(x-a))**3, (-2*h<=x-a)&(x-a<=-h)),
    ...:  (2*h**3/3-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), (-h<= x-a)&(x-a<= 0)),
    ...:  (2*(h**3/3)-0.5*(x-a)**2*(2*h+(x-a)), (0<=x-a)&(x-a<=2*h)),
    ...:  ((1/6)*(2*h-(x-a))**3, (h<=x-a)&(x-a<=2*h)), (0, x-a<=2*h))

In [24]: expr
Out[24]: 
array([-0.5*(x + 1)**2*(x + 2.0) + 0.0833333333333333,
       -0.5*(x + 1)**2*(x + 2.0) + 0.0833333333333333], dtype=object)

In [26]: p = lambdify((x,), expr)
```

`x` is the only sympy symbol in `expr`.

Looking at the resulting function:

```
In [27]: print(p.__doc__)
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x)

Expression:

[-0.5*(x + 1)**2*(x + 2.0) + 0.0833333333333333  -0.5*(x + 1)**2*(x + 2.0)...

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x):
    return ([-0.5*(x + 1)**2*(x + 2.0) + 0.0833333333333333, -0.5*(x + 1)**2*(x + 2.0) + 0.0833333333333333])
```

Comment: Standard way to do chained inequalities both for numpy and sympy is `(a < b) & (b < c)`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you so much, this is extremely helpful! Really appreciate you taking it step by step and writing it all out in depth. Many thanks for your help, I learnt something new.

Comment: Is one able to plot the function generated?